# pandas Identify cycles in a timeseries data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, statsmodels

I have timeseries data and I want to **identify cycles and duration of each cycle**.

- The datetime index does not have a frequency (there is no fixed time step between data point)

I tried to **decompose** the series using `seasonal_decompose` from `statsmodels.tsa.seasonal` but I got the following error  `ValueError: You must specify a period or x must be a pandas object with a DatetimeIndex with a freq not set to None`

Comment: can you provide a reproducible dataset?

Answer (score 0):

First resample your processed DataFrame in a variable say y (make sure that the index is of datetime type)

Then pass that variable in seasonal_decompose

Ex:

```
y = df['Sales'].resample('MS').mean()
x = seasonal_decompose(y)
#plot the decomposed data
x.plot()
#show the plot
plt.show()
```